# ACPI – how to select correct LED and LCD module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, acpi, asus, backlight

I'm facing a strange issue. I have ASUS x551ma notebook; As I can get it, after a while (20-30 min) watching LCD, I suffer eye strain. The graphics (video card) seems fine but the LED is micro-shaking a bit or something similar,
so it is very tiring.
As a result, I am not sure I have my device correct ACPI module running.

Moreover, I tried to insert the `asus_laptop` module,
but I get the error output:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'asus_laptop': No such device
```

...which shouldn't be, because in fact I do have an ASUS notebook :(

So my question is...

- How to find out what is wrong with the LED module?
- Is there an alternative module for ASUS notebooks?
- If there are no existing ASUS modules,
  then how can I fix/patch the current one?

My setup:

- OS Arch Linux x64
- kernel 3.16.7
- notebook ASUS x551ma (Intel HD Graphics)

Comment: I would guess that your version of the asus notebook is not either not supported by the module or not detected. Sometimes it helps to read the driver code in /usr/src/linux, or where you have it. /usr/src/linux/Documentation is a very good source of information too.

Comment: As you ask for information: Check `/usr/src/linux` or where you have your linux kernel source, `Documentation/laptops/asus-laptop.txt`. In the last section of that text file is a mailing list mentioned and a sourceforge page, where you can check for patches. Sorry: I changed as a comment: The sourceforge page is discontinued.

Comment: @ikrabbe I am a bit new to linux; please give more details of how to get the info you talk about "/usr/src/linux" I mean give detailed terminal command(s)?

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: @ikrabbe have linux-3.16.7 sources; I just watched the "linux-3.16.7/Documentation/laptops/asus_laptop.txt" file;  What exactly should I look there at? As I can get it, the non-insertable asus_laptop version is 0.1 :P I am not sure what if the asus notebook led driver needs a firmware or something?

Comment: Moreover, I just watched the "/linux-3.16.7/Documentation/backlight/lp855x-driver.txt" which says the driver is fine for "LP8550, LP8551, LP8552, LP8553, LP8555, LP8556 and LP8557" chips only :P So how to find out which chip I have on my notebook? Is there a linux util which can output the info?

Comment: check lspci and dmidecode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25482/discussion-between-ikrabbe-and-user390525).

Answer (score 0):

The path `/usr/src/linux` is the standard path where kernel sources live in a linux system.

Depending on your distribution you can install linux kernel sources with your package manager, or you go to http://www.kernel.org and download and extract one.

#### Download a kernel with git

One of the most powerful ways is to download a kernel with git as super-user (root)

```
cd /usr/src
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
```

will create a directory `/usr/src/linux`.

#### Download a kernel by hand

```
cd /usr/src
# go to http://www.kernel.org and select the latest stable (for example) copying the link with your favorite browser (below for the current version)
curl -o linux-4.1.1.tar.xz 'https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.1.1.tar.xz'
xz -cd linux-4.1.1.tar.xz | tar xf -
```

I think the tar archives contain the linux directory with a version extension. It's common (I dislike that) to link linux to your latest kernel

```
ln -s linux-4.1.1 linux
```

## The Documentation

Just read a bit. When you have the kernel source in that path just look in `/usr/src/linux/Documentation` for files. When I look for topics I like to grep for them

```
grep -rin 'asus-laptop' /usr/src/linux/Documentation
```

Gives

```
/usr/src/linux/Documentation/laptops/00-INDEX:5:asus-laptop.txt
/usr/src/linux/Documentation/laptops/asus-laptop.txt:48:  Try "modprobe asus-laptop". Check your dmesg (simply type dmesg). You should
/usr/src/linux/Documentation/laptops/asus-laptop.txt:65:  /sys/devices/platform/asus-laptop/infos entry. If you have a question or a
/usr/src/linux/Documentation/laptops/asus-laptop.txt:81:  /sys/class/backlight/asus-laptop/. Brightness Values are between 0 and 15.
/usr/src/linux/Documentation/laptops/asus-laptop.txt:110:  /sys/devices/platform/asus-laptop/display. The significance of those values
/usr/src/linux/Documentation/laptops/asus-laptop.txt:159:  2) Echo values from 0 to 15 to /sys/devices/platform/asus-laptop/display.
/usr/src/linux/Documentation/laptops/asus-laptop.txt:169:    echo $((10#$arg-60)) > /sys/devices/platform/asus-laptop/display
/usr/src/linux/Documentation/laptops/asus-laptop.txt:188:    echo 0x0T000DDD > /sys/devices/platform/asus-laptop/
/usr/src/linux/Documentation/laptops/asus-laptop.txt:208:  For example "echo 0x01000001 >/sys/devices/platform/asus-laptop/ledd"
/usr/src/linux/Documentation/laptops/asus-laptop.txt:214: Options can be passed to the asus-laptop driver using the standard
/usr/src/linux/Documentation/laptops/asus-laptop.txt:216: module or asus-laptop.<param>=<value> on the kernel boot line when
/usr/src/linux/Documentation/laptops/asus-laptop.txt:217: asus-laptop is statically linked into the kernel).
/usr/src/linux/Documentation/laptops/asus-laptop.txt:249: - a copy of /sys/devices/platform/asus-laptop/infos
/usr/src/linux/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-platform-asus-laptop:34:         The DDD table can be found in Documentation/laptops/asus-laptop.txt
```

on my system.

Now you know where you can read about the topic, you are searching for.